# Jquery Gauge, pointer exceeds the highest value of the arc. How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gauge, jsgauge

I am creating a Jquery Gauge. In this way, the largest value of the arc is '100', but if I set the pointer value to '110', it overflows the arc limit, like the image:
[image: Pointer overflows the limit of 100]

Someway to resolve this problem or set a 'max value'/'range' for the pointer?
NOTE: The pointer can't exceed the arc limit.

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Gauge 8</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, maximum-scale=1">
<link href="jquery-gauge.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
    .demo1 {
        position: relative;
        width: 10vw;
        height: 10vw;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float:left;
        margin:20px
    }
    .demo3 {
        position: relative;
        width: 9vw;
        height: 9vw;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float:left;
        margin:20px
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="gauge3 demo3"></div>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-gauge.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     $('.gauge3').gauge({
         values: {
             0 : '0',
             25: '25',
             50: '50',
             75: '75',
             100: '100'
         },
         colors: {
             0 : 'green',
             30: 'orange',
             40: 'red'
         },
         angles: [
             180,
             360
         ],
         lineWidth: 9,
         arrowWidth: 5,
         arrowColor: 'black',
         inset:true,

         value: 110
     });
 </script>

 <div class="gauge1 demo1"></div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Which gauge plugin is it you're using?

Comment: This: http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-jQuery-Plugin-For-Creating-SVG-Based-Gauges.html

Comment: `value > 110 ? 100 : value;`

Comment: Its a feature :) not a bug.

Comment: @Kriggs not understand your placement

Comment: @BasvanStein, is possible to resolve this?

Comment: You have to either change the code of the gauge plugin or prevent the user from setting it higher than max yourself.

Comment: @JulioCesarBoaroli That's a tertiary statement, it's a shorter if...else, you can read it as: is value greater than 110? If yes, return `100`, other case, return `value`. It's wrong nevertherless, it should be `value > 100`.